# How to delay execution of script while using Laravel's chunk feature?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to delay the execution of a script by a few seconds after it processes say 200 records using Laravel's chunk method. Here's what I've right now. Should I put a counter somewhere? But then that will not work I believe, are there other techniques?

```
    Article::chunk(200, function ($articles)
    { 
        foreach ($articles as $article)
        {

        }

    });
```

Thanks to WereWolf, it worked. Can't believe it was so simple.

```
[2014-08-27 07:18:23] local.INFO: Article metrics:198 [] []
[2014-08-27 07:18:24] local.INFO: Article metrics:199 [] []
[2014-08-27 07:18:24] local.INFO: Article metrics:200 [] []
[2014-08-27 07:18:30] local.INFO: Article metrics:201 [] []
[2014-08-27 07:18:34] local.INFO: Article metrics:202 [] []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function, for example:

```
Article::chunk(200, function ($articles) {

    foreach ($articles as $article) {

        // ...

    }

    sleep(2); // Delay the script execution for 2 seconds
});
```

Comment: I know but where exactly, in my setting. I can't use it at the loop naturally that would incur a long time delay. I want it to delay the script every 200 (so if there are 1000 records, there would be 5 delays)

Comment: I think with cURL being used simultaneously, will this will give me some relief, given some public APIs would throttle my connection after a certain threshold.

Comment: Use of `sleep` actually halts everything in the script, no code will run.

Comment: Yes, maybe there is a certain threshold for one of the public APIs I am using which says that the user may only perform 200 requests in this given period of time, so I am trying to ease on a bit by delaying the script, which in turn delays the cURL requests to their endpoints.